# Flutter: Object generation from jSON with dynamic variables

Tags: json, object, flutter, dart

With dart / flutter it is possible to instantiate an Dart object from a jSON object.
For example, you define the dart class and instantiate an object of that class with the content from a jSON string via the API query.

The question is:
Is there any way that the jSON object contains additional variables that are then also available in the instantiated dart object? The goal is an ultra dynamic App, which is only supplied by the backend.

So far, I've been working with 'fixed' variable names or lists of subobjects.
This approach works perfectly smoothly.
I have not tried the approach of a dynamic variable from a jSON string yet.
I would like to ask if this is possible in principle before I design a concept based on this approach.

```
{
    "widgetType": "radioGroup",
    "label": "Level",
    "integerValueNew": 200
}


@JsonSerializable()
class Input {
    Input();

    @JsonKey(required: true) String widgetType;
    String label;

    factory Input.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$InputFromJson(json);
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$InputToJson(this);
}
```

In the Dart class only the variables 'widgetType' and 'label' are defined. Also the type of the variable is known, when an objekt is instantiated.

Can a dart object be instantiated from the shown jSON object, which then also contains the integer 'integerValueNew'?

If that works, you can develop a concept for it.
If not, I would work with sub-objects and well-defined variable names in Dart classes. Then the concept has to be broken down to a simple key value mapping.

I also do not know how the dart object should know which type of variable it is at all.

Comment: Have you ever got this to work?